# <%= link_to_remote>,Change Hyperlink Text Color Onmouseclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I need to change the clicked hyperlink text's color when clicking on it, that is part of a div. There are many hyperlinks in the same div, as below:

```
 <div id="link"<br>
    <b>Period:</b>
    (<%= link_to_remote "Today", :url =>{:action =>'period_list',:period=>"today"},:onmouseclick=>"changeColor(this,'#FF0000');"%>/
     <%= link_to_remote "This week", :url =>{:action =>'period_list',:period=>"weeks"}%>/
     <%= link_to_remote "This month", :url =>{:action =>'period_list',:period=>"months"}%>
  </div>
```

in `<head>` the code below is given:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function changeColor(idObj,colorObj)
{
    document.getElementById(idObj.id).style.color = colorObj;
}
</script>
```

but, after clicking on 'today', the text color will not change.

Can you please give a solution to solve this.

thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You don't give ID to the link, so idObj.id return blank string and `document.getElementById(idObj.id)` returns NULL.

To fix this have such code instead:

```
idObj.style.color = colorObj;
```